# How to iterate over nested items

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, loops, nokogiri

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="date">
  <h3 class="date-title">Today</h3>

  <div class="film">
    <img class="poster" src="film1" />
      <h4 class="title">Film 1</h4>
    <ul class="session-times">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <time>12:00 PM</time>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.film -->

  <div class="film">
    <img class="poster" src="film2" />
      <h4 class="title">Film 2</h4>
    <ul class="session-times">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <time>3:00 PM</time>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.film -->

  <div class="film">
    <img class="poster" src="film3" />
      <h4 class="title">Film 3</h4>
    <ul class="session-times">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <time>6:00 PM</time>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.film -->
</div><!-- /.date -->

<div class="date">
  <h3 class="date-title">Tomorrow</h3>

  <div class="film">
    <img class="poster" src="film1" />
      <h4 class="title">Film 1</h4>
    <ul class="session-times">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <time>2:00 PM</time>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.film -->

  <div class="film">
    <img class="poster" src="film2" />
      <h4 class="title">Film 2</h4>
    <ul class="session-times">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <time>5:00 PM</time>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.film -->

  <div class="film">
    <img class="poster" src="film3" />
      <h4 class="title">Film 3</h4>
    <ul class="session-times">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <time>8:00 PM</time>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.film -->
</div><!-- /.date -->
```

and I'm extracting data using this Ruby code:

```
nokogiri_object.css('.date').each do |d|
  date = d.css('.date-title').text
  dates.push(date: date)
  d.css('.film').each do |film|
    title = film.css('.title')
    title_en = title.text.strip
    time = film.css('.session-times/li/a/time').text
  end
end
```

This gives me:

```
[
  {
    "date": "Today"
  },
  {
    "date": "Tomorrow"
  }
]
```

but I'd like to loop over the three movies `n` times in each `.film` section and include them under each date in the output, so it should look more like this:

```
[
  {
    "Today": {
      "films": [
        {
          "film": "Film1",
          "time": "12:00 PM"
        },
        {
          "film": "Film2",
          "time": "15:00 PM"
        },
        {
          "film": "Film3",
          "time": "6:00 PM"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    "Tomorrow": {
      "films": [
        {
          "film": "Film1",
          "time": "14:00 PM"
        },
        {
          "film": "Film2",
          "time": "5:00 PM"
        },
        {
          "film": "Film3",
          "time": "8:00 PM"
        }
      ]
  },
```

I can't figure out where to build my array within the nested loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is first find the nodes with class `date` (an array of Nokogiri nodes). And transform this array (with `map` method) in the structure you want. The result will be an array (because `map`) of hashes (because is what I return in the external `map`). To create the structure you want in any hash I use the same concepts: find nokogiri nodes with the `css` method and `map` every result in what you want.

```
 date_nodes = nokogiri_object.css('.date')
 date_nodes.map do |date| 
   { 
     date.css('.date-title').text => { 
       "films" => date.css('.film').map do |film| 
         { 
           "film" => film.css('img.poster').attr('src').value, 
           "time" => film.css('time').text 
         }
       end 
     }
   }  
 end
 => [{"Today"=>{
   "films"=>[
     {"film"=>"film1", "time"=>"12:00 PM"}, 
     {"film"=>"film2", "time"=>"3:00 PM"}, 
     {"film"=>"film3", "time"=>"6:00 PM"}]}}, 
   {"Tomorrow"=>{
   "films"=>[
     {"film"=>"film1", "time"=>"2:00 PM"}, 
     {"film"=>"film2", "time"=>"5:00 PM"}, 
     {"film"=>"film3", "time"=>"8:00 PM"}]}}
  ]
```

Comment: Rather than toss out code, also provide an explanation of what the code does. The idea is we're educating, not just supply a solution. It's the difference between giving someone a fish or teaching them to fish.

Comment: I don't think the author can't understand my code. I think usually it's hard for a beginner/not expert think how to solve a problem but show them a solution doesn't mean they can't understand the solution

Comment: And the author can always ask for details or explanation if he wants!

Comment: Answers here are for everyone who came here for a solution, not strictly for OP, and code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: The author didn't ask for explanation about theory concepts, he wanted this code

Comment: I don't expect upvote. I don't expect downvote, it's very different.

Comment: Is better now? Is ok?